# Get HTML fragment without text by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML code with `div` container and another HTML element and text inside it

```
<div id="container"><i class="myico"></i> text</div>
```

I need to get **only HTML** element from the container **without the text**.

So i need to get only

```
<i class="myico"></i>
```

How can I get it using jQuery?

Comment: I exactly need to change text and get HTML `<div id="container"><i class="myico"></i> another txt changed</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply to get the element use one of the following:

```
var element = $("#container > i");
var element = $("#container i");
var element = $("#container .myico");
var element = $("#container").find("i.myico");
```

To get the element out of the markup use [`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/):

```
var element = $("#container > i").detach();
```

Then to get an HTML code, you may use `outerHTML` property:

```
var html = element.get(0).outerHTML;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tLvdZ/

Comment: But how Can I get to this markup and put it to another container. This solution doesn't work `$('#cont2').html($("#container > i").detach() + 'other text')`

Comment: @Cichy Try this: `$("#container i").appendTo("#cont2");` or this: `$("#cont2").append($("#container i"), "other text");`. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tLvdZ/1/.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved my problem with your suggestions http://jsfiddle.net/tLvdZ/5/

Answer (score 0):

`$('i') / $('.myico') / $('div i')`... http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmltag = $("#container").html();
htmltag = htmltag.replace($("#container").text(),"");
```

For reference you can use :- [refer this](http://jsfiddle.net/jigneshparmar/Jk6YK/)